# Is it possible to work with database in django shell without pre-installed app?

Tags: python, django

Without defining an app's models in models.py, i want to work with models such as defining a model class and creating/deleting/modifying object of this model. How can i do this in django shell?

I tried this in django shell.

```py
from django.db import models
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date_published')
```

This causes `runtimeerror`.

> RuntimeError: Model class **main**.Question doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Every model is related to the django app. You cannot use django shell for creating a model.